# Rounding to the nearest all number in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to write a function that will round up to the nearest whole number in sql server 2008.
May be there is already that function.

When rounding I need to have 2 decimal places.

EG

If a number is less than 5 "4.4" round it to 4 if more than "5" 4.6 than round it to 5

Examples:

2.664543=2.70

4.2432=4.20

How can I do it in sql server?

many thanks

Comment: Those examples you show are *not* rounding to 2 decimal places. They're rounding to one decimal place and then showing an additional 0. To 2 decimal places they would be `2.66` and `4.24`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ROUND function for that.

```
ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )
SELECT ROUND(4.4, 0) -- Gives 4.0
SELECT ROUND(4.6, 0) -- Gives 5.0
SELECT ROUND(2.664543, 1)  -- Gives 2.70000
SELECT ROUND(4.2432, 1) -- Gives 4.2000

SELECT CAST(ROUND(4.2432, 1) as NUMERIC(36,2))  -- Gives 4.20
```

Comment: Excellent thanks.so to get the 2 decimal places I have to do SELECT CAST(ROUND(MyValue, 1) as NUMERIC(36,2)) .Can you explain "Numeric(36,2)"

Comment: In NUMERIC(36,2). 36 is the precision for the value and 2 is the scale. You should use DECIMAL OR NUMERIC depending on your column datatype. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258832(v=sql.80).aspx